# Are there any for java sdks for IBM cloud object storage (IBM COS), and where can I find some examples?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, object-storage, cloud-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am planing to use IBM COS as an object storage solution. Are there any SDKs for JAVA which can be used for authentication and managing the objects via REST calls ?

I am able to connect to the bucket using cyberDuck. But need to manage the objects using Java and Rest APIs.

I am able to authenticate in postman using authorization type as 'AWS Signature', and giving my AccessKey and SecretKey, leaving advanced fields empty. I see that 3 Headers are added after this - Host, X-Amz-Date and Authorization.

Authorization headers starts like AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=********

Answer (score 1):

Yes here is the info on the IBM Cloud Object Storage Java SDK
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#using-java

Comment: Thanks. Found that we have artifactId : 'ibm-cos-java-sdk' under groupId: 'com.ibm.cos'